# YADCF Multiselect Return Empty Record

Tags: php, datatable, server-side, yadcf

The **datatable** and **YADCF** does **not** return any record when using **multiselect** filter from **YADCF** plugins

Here the screenshot
[image: Empty Record when search multiple value using multiselect filter]

Using Below JS Scripts

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    'use strict';

     var oTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );

    yadcf.init(oTable, [
        {
            column_number: 0,
            filter_type: 'multi_select',
            select_type: 'select2'
        }
    ]);
} );
```

Here the respond parameter snip

[image]

I use serverside and php, but I think this is not PHP/SQL problem rather than Javascripts problem, but I dont know how to do it..

Thank You..

Comment: you should add some code to your php that will read/parse the columns[0][search][value] and will return the relevant rows back to your client